# Item List selection issue in Mozilla in content editable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my page when i start selecting the list content starting from the mid point of bullet and text, It starts dragging the text.

```html
<ul contenteditable="true">
<li >anatomy, and behavior</li>

<li >Understand current conservation efforts</li>

<li>often associate with sharks</li>
</ul>
```

It works fine in Chrome.
It is replicable when we click exactly at the mid point of Bullet and text.

Comment: Interesting bug! Not really surprising when we know bad implementation regarding contenteditable on FF